# Cut vertices and cut edges - did I answer these correctly?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Problem**

Find the cut vertices and cut edges for the following graphs

[image: cuts]

**My understanding of the definitions:**

A cut vertex is a vertex that when removed (with its boundary edges) from a graph creates more components than previously in the graph.

A cut edge is an edge that when removed (the vertices stay in place) from a graph creates more components than previously in the graph.

**My Answers**

31) The cut vertex is $c$.  There are no cut edges.

32) The cut vertices are $c$ and $d$.  The cut edge is $(c,d)$

33) The cut vertices are $b, c, d$ and $i$.  The cut edges are: $(a,b)$,$(b,c)$,$(c,d)$,$(c,e)$,$(e,i)$,$(i,h)$

**For anyone reading this at a later date:**

33) is wrong, per the answers and comments below, e is a cut vertex, not d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct except that in $33$, $d$ is not a cutvertex and $e$ is.

Answer (score 3):

Good job except on 33) $d$ is not a cut vertix and $e$ is .
and the cut edges are $(b,c) ,(c,e) ,(e,i)$
32) and 31) seems correct for me .

Comment: I believe the cut edges for 33) are still $(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(c,e),(e,i),(i,h)$.  For example, when edge $(a,b)$ is removed, vertex $a$ still exists as a separate component.

Comment: you are right i am sorry for misleading you.

Comment: No, I appreciate your help.  Thank you.